# SQL Query Not Yielding results

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table with record size for various clusters along with date cluster was scanned.I need to get the size for each cluster in each month based on latest scanned date. 
I am trying the below query in Impala SQL but it does not yield a result.

```
Scandata    cluster  Size
11/4/2017   ABC 200
11/18/2017  ABC 700
11/25/2017  ABC 1009
12/4/2017   ABC 200
12/18/2017  ABC 700
12/20/2017  ABC 1100
1/4/2018    ABC 200
1/18/2018   ABC 700
1/20/2018   ABC 1009
11/4/2017   CAD 200
11/18/2017  CAD 700
11/25/2017  CAD 1009
12/4/2017   CAD 200
12/18/2017  CAD 700
12/20/2017  CAD 1100
```

result expected

```
Data    cluster  Size
11/25/2017  ABC 1009
12/20/2017  ABC 1100
1/20/2018   ABC 1009
11/25/2017  CAD 1009
12/20/2017  CAD 1100


SELECT t.*
FROM arxview.test_summary t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MONTH(scandate) AS month, MAX(DAY(scandate)) AS day, cluster
 FROM arxview.test_summary t
 GROUP BY MONTH(scandate), cluster) sub
ON (MONTH(t.scandate) = sub.month AND DAY(t.scandate) = sub.day AND t.cluster = sub.cluster)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method uses window functions:

```
select ts.*
from (select ts.*,
             max(scandate) over (partition by year(scandate), month(scandate) as max_scandate_monthly
      from arxview.test_summary t
     ) ts
where scandate = max_scandate_monthly;
```